# Display dropdown menu horizontally

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web

I am trying to get my drop down menu links to display horizontally instead of vertically.

```
<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="about.html">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Products</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <ul class='list-inline'>
                    <li><a href="products1.html" id="">This is a product page</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="products2.html" id="">This is also a product page</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" id="">3</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" id="">4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" id="">5</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I am using one of the standard bootstrap templates. The title for each product page are a few words but the text in there now is just as an example.

[image]

With new purposed css:
[proposed answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXNIm.jpg)

Comment: .list-inline li add dispaly:inline-block;

Comment: Where do I add that at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a fast one on Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dGZgOZ

You can use the `display:table/-row/-cell` to force the dropdown horizontal.

**And I fixed the `<ul><ul>...</ul></ul>`** so the HTML is valid.

Code:

```
.nav {


list-style: none;
}
.nav > li {
  float: left;
}
.nav > li.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
  display: table;
}
.nav > li .dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: #ccc;
}
.nav > li .dropdown-menu .list-inline {
  display: table-row;
}
.nav > li .dropdown-menu .list-inline > li {
  display: table-cell;
  list-style: none;
}
```

**Edit:** added `:hover`

Comment: I need it to be a drop down menu though that is making it static underneath the main "products" link

Comment: Yes, perfect!! Thanks a lot for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

add css

```
.navbar-nav{margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none;}
.navbar-nav li{float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 30px;}
.list-inline{    position: absolute;
    width: 205px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;}
 .list-inline li{
          display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vmwj5w4L/3/

Comment: Adding that to the css just caused the links in the nav bar to shift left and then I lose the white background in my dropdown menu, I edited my question with a image showing changes in css